# How to Check if a SSL Certificate is successfully renewed

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, centos6

I have two web servers, one for an intranet and the other for a website. The system specs of the two are almost the same, which is as follows:

CentOS 6.5
LAMP (Apache/2.2.15) + WordPress, which were installed with yum command

I am trying to renew their wildcard SSL certificate with a new one, which I recently got from GoDaddy. The zip file sent from GoDaddy includes the followings:

c************.crt
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
gd_intermediate.crt

The two servers share the same private key (test.key), which I am going to use for the new certificate too. So the 2 steps below is all I did on both servers.

(Step 1)
Copy the three files above to /etc/pki/tls/certs directory and edit the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf so the keys "SSLCertificateFile" and "SSLCertificateChainFile" point to the new respective file. The file looks like below after editting.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/c************.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/test.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
        <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName *****.*********.com
</VirtualHost>
```

(Step 2)
Restart the server

After the steps, I accessed both servers with google chrome and checked to see if the expiration date had changed. The expiration date on the intranet has changed like I had expected.

(before)
Valid from 6/17/2014 to 6/17/2015
(after)
Valid from 5/18/2014 to 6/17/2016

But the date on the website is still the same. Is there any other way to check if the certificate is successfully renewed? Or is there anything wrong about the steps I followed? I did not get any errors when I went through the steps and I am thinking that there might be some more steps I need to do to get a wildcard certificate to work.

Comment: Why haven't you installed the GoDaddy Secure Server Certificate (Intermediate Certificate) gd_intermediate.crt.  without that you have a broken validation chain.

Comment: Thank you for help me. That was because of my misconfiguration. By the way I don't really know the difference between gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt and gd_intermediate.crt. they both worked, so I just picked gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt. Should I always choose gd_intermediate.crt instead of gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remember  - Apache uses **either** `httpd.conf` or `ssl.conf` depending on how Apache was configured - since `ssl.conf` is preferred make sure the "failing" server is NOT using `ssl.conf` instead.

2) Have you tried copying the `httpd.conf` file from the working server to the "failing" server.  If everything else is the same, that should make SSL work, if it doesn't everything is NOT the same on the two servers - double check

Comment: Thank you! You saved me! I needed to edit SSLCertificateFile key in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf. After restaring, it showed the new expiration date.